# Sum failure times in dataframe based on date and component in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have two dataframes and am trying to come up with failure times based on the date and component in the second dataframe. The first dataframe df1 contains the date and component that had a failure. The second dataframe df2 is the date and Time (hours) accumulated on that date by component.

| Failure Date | Component |
| --- | --- |
| 09/25/2022 | A1 |
| 09/27/2022 | A2 |
| 09/29/2022 | A1 |

| Date | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09/30/2022 | 5 | 5 |
| 09/29/2022 | 2 | 0 |
| 09/28/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 09/27/2022 | 0 | 5 |
| 09/26/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 09/25/2022 | 8 | 0 |
| 09/24/2022 | 0 | 5 |
| 09/23/2022 | 9 | 5 |

What I am trying to come up with is a table that lists Time (hours) from beginning to failure date and total time like below:

| Failure Times | Total Time |
| --- | --- |
| 17 | 24 |
| 15 | 20 |
| 19 |  |

So 17 is 9/23-9/25 for A1 which is 8+9 Hours

For the total time I simply did:

```
df2 = df2.sum(axis=0)
```

So far what I tried is to do which gets me a sum of the time from the first date in df1:

```
df3 = df1[~(df1['Failure Date'] >  df2.at[0, 'Date'])]
df4 = df3.sum(axis=0)
```

New to python so from there I am stuck. I believe I have to pull the component Sum of Time from df4 and merge it back into df1 where it matches and then loop through to get the remaining component failure times. I then need to take the Failure Time and Total Time columns and add them to a new dataframe.
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to show the calculation made in the expected result based on the data above. Secondly, you're referring to time, but there is only a date

Comment: @naveed. I have updated how the calculation was made as well as noted that Time is in Hours in df2 in which each component, A1 or A2, operated.